# When using LIKE with % in MySQL PDO, row with a capital not returned

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Okay so say I am doing a search for "PersonName" and I type in "person" it doesn't find the person but "Person" does, is there a way to tell it to look for anything resembling my input?

I am doing the search simply like this:

```
$db->sqlquery("
SELECT `user_id` 
FROM `users`
WHERE `username`LIKE ?", array("%$user%"));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends on the collation of the field.

If the collation ends _cs then it's case sensitive, if it ends _ci then case insensitive.

Change the properties of the field and the indexes / search will follow.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to try ILIKE instead of LIKE in your query?